# SQL query to add column from excel sheet to mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

The table in mySQL database is same as that of the excel sheet. However, the sheet has an extra column that i wish to add in the mysql table.

Columns in table say abc: id,name,dob
Columns in sheet say pqr: id,name,dob,gender

now, i wish to add the gender column from excel sheet to my table corresponding to the particular id without dropping the table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/pqr.csv' 
INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

but this will be used for new import and not update the table.

Comment: you should really recreate the table on the SQL side, then stage the file load into a staging table, then just use a insert into statement from the staging table to the fact table. hope that helps - without dropping you have a blank set of rows for gender until the day you start using the column

Comment: or you can alter the table - add the column, stage another table that includes the record ID and the gender value, then run a set update set statement to set the gender values based on the ID from the staging table

Answer (score 0):

> Columns in table say abc: id,name,dob
>
> Columns in sheet say pqr: id,name,dob,gender

Create a temporary table `temporary`, import the data into this table, then alter the `abc` adding a new column `gender`, then update the gender in `abc` using `temporary`, finally delete `temporary`.

```
CREATE TABLE temporary (id int, name varchar(100), dob date, gender char(1), PRIMARY KEY (id));

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/pqr.csv'  
INTO TABLE temporary  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'  

ALTER TABLE abc ADD COLUMN (gender varchar(1));

UPDATE abc  
SET gender = (SELECT gender FROM temporary WHERE temporary.id = abc.id);

-- some DBs need a FROM clause, use either one which works
UPDATE abc  
SET gender = (SELECT gender FROM temporary WHERE temporary.id = abc.id)  
FROM temporary;

SELECT * FROM abc;

DROP TABLE temporary;
```

Without knowing which DBMS you are using, the answer cannot be more specific.